# Cocoa NSDocument: getting autosave to work

Tags: cocoa, nsdocument, nsdocumentcontroller

Documentation simply states that setting `setAutosavingDelay` to anything > 0 on the shared doc controller should do it, but after calling

```
[[NSDocumentController sharedDocumentController] setAutosavingDelay:2.0];
```

in my controller, autosave doesn't seem to work: I neither see anything in `~/Library/Autosave Information/`, nor is

```
[[[NSDocumentController sharedDocumentController] currentDocument] autosavedContentsFileURL]
```

initialized.

Note that in my app, normal loading and saving work fine (keyedarchivers, nscoding-based class for my docs, etc).

Comment: Just as a sanity check, you did make a change to the document so there was something to auto save? (and see what -hasUnautosavedChanges reports)

Comment: and your NSDocument return yes for autosavesInPlace?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you overridden -updateChangeCount: at all? I'm pretty certain that Apple's implementation is the code that starts up the autosave timer. Also, what if you experiment with a longer timer?

Comment: Thanks. I haven't. I'll give both a try and get back.

Answer (score 2):

Some people find that the directory 
~/Library/Autosave Information
is owned by root, and so files can not be written therein. See for example 
http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2252306

I don't know how the bug arises but I was bitten by it -- the directory was created 2010-06-17 12:19 and I assume that the permissions were wrong from that moment.